# Rails 4, content not displaying?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've recently come across the Youtube_addy gem and it's perfect for what I am currently working on.

Gem [HERE](https://github.com/hanzq/youtube_addy)

I do have a few questions to the SO community though.

Basically, my app allows users to submit youtube links and rank them. I will be using Youtube addy to dynamically embed the video on the show page for the link submitted. For each submission.

I'm having trouble with this particular function:

```
  <iframe width="#{width}" height="#{height}" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/#{@video_tag}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I can't seem to get the video_id part to work. I've added this to the song_controller.rb show action with no luck:

```
def show
     @video_tag = YouTubeAddy.extract_video_id(@song.url)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to post this as a comment but regardless of what I did the message kept popping up 'only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified', so I'm doing it here instead.

The function is in your show.html.erb? I think you have to embed your ruby code with erb notation: `<%= @whatever %>` So `src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/#{@video_tag}"` might be something like `src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<%= @video_tag %>"`

Comment: The comment was not being accepted due to multiple '@'Something strings in the comment.  These strings will be interpreted as "pings".  More information on this available here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300376/why-cant-i-comment-on-an-answer-to-my-stackoverflow-post.  Information about stackoverflow issues in general can be searched for here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/.